# Matching periods in a string to underscores in a string

Tags: regex, bash

I am working on creating a bash script to automatically place videos in a Plex Library. For shows that ive seen so far, the following regex works fine to detect the show name, season, and episode number.

```
#TV Show Name
sed -n 's/\(.*\).S[0-9]\{1,\}.*/\1/p'
#TV Show Season
sed -n 's/.*\(S[0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
#TV Show Episode
sed -n 's/.*S[0-9]*\(E[0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

The real trouble comes when moving the videos to the Plex Library. All the videos that are being placed in folder to be processed by the script use periods '.' as spaces.

For example,
Once.Upon.A.Time.S01E01.avi, Marvels.Agents.Of.S.H.I.E.L.D.S01E01.avi, etc

Since the Plex Library format uses underscores '_' to represent spaces (this is on a Linux server), I just use sed to replace the periods in the TV Show name with underscores. I then use grep -i to match it with the correct folder containing the TV Show in the Plex Library folder and use the rest of the show/episode number to put the file in the right place. Funny enough, one of the shows (Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. in fact) happens to come with periods in its name.

Is there an easy way to match together the file name and the plex folder name without having the underscore problem described above?

Or should I simply set an exception for this particular show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the show name as it exists prior to converting dots to underscores and convert all dots to question marks instead (e.g. `sed "s/\./\?/g"`) you can then feed that name (e.g. `Marvels?Agents?Of?S?H?I?E?L?D`) to find to locate the appropriate Plex Library directory.

`find /path/to/library -type d -iname "Marvels?Agents?Of?S?H?I?E?L?D"`

That should give you the directory you need for moving the file and would also allow you to work backwards to properly convert the dots in the file name to underscores, if desired.

Comment: Works exactly as described and learned something new :)
Thanks!